# Get column based on changing bool values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df like this

```
id  bool
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   0
4   0
5   1
```

And then i need to get сolumn with id and new bool value, where the value of bool changes.
Like this :

```
id bool
0   1
3   0
5   1
```

I can do this by using for, but is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
out = df[df['bool'].ne(df['bool'].shift())]
```

Or with [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
out = df[df['bool'].diff().ne(0)]
```

Output:

```
   id  bool
0   0     1
3   3     0
5   5     1
```

Comment: Thank you, dataframe can be studied endlessly

Comment: @Fresto I'm not sure I got you comment, did it work as expected?

Comment: yes, it worked as expected